# Queryselector not finding <progress> element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I want to program an clicker html game and I have some basic code. I want to display the amount of Wood in an progress element. If it is near the maximal amount, I want to color my progress bar differently. I think

```
var woodBar = document.querySelector("progress, .mywoodprogressbarid");
```

should work. Then I add a new class if my condition(near full) is TRUE and style that in css. I have already done this for the food element, but for the wood element it doesn't work :( I´m not sure why...
Here is my code(1) for food 2) for wood):

```
<div id="Food">
   <p style="text-align:center; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 30px; color:#ffff; margin-bottom:30px;">Essen</p>
   <p id="foodAmountText" style="text-align:center; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size:20px; color:#ffff;">0 / 1000</p>
   <progress id="FoodProgressBar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
   <div>
     <label style="float:right; margin-right:5px; margin-top:25px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color:#ffff;">+1/sek</label>
     <button id="FoodButton" class="ClickButton" type="button" onclick="grindFood()">Essen Kochen</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Now the js code:

```
var foodProgressColor = document.querySelector("progress, .FoodProgressBar");
        cosnole.log(foodProgressColor);
        if (maxFood - foodCount <= maxFood / 100 * 10 ) {
          foodProgressColor.classList.add("Over10");
        }
        else {
          foodProgressColor.classList.remove("Over10");
        }
        if (maxFood - foodCount <= maxFood / 100 * 50 && maxFood - foodCount > maxFood / 100 * 10) {
          foodProgressColor.classList.add("Over50");
        }
        else{
          foodProgressColor.classList.remove("Over50");
        }
```

HTML wood:

```
<div id="Wood">
         <p style="text-align:center; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 30px; color:#ffff; margin-bottom:30px;">Holz</p>
     <p id="woodAmountText" style="text-align:center; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size:20px; color:#ffff;">0 / 1000</p>
     <progress id="WoodProgressBar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
     <div>
       <label style="float:right; margin-right:5px; margin-top:25px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color:#ffff;">+1/sek</label>
       <button id="WoodButton" class="ClickButton" type="button" onclick="grindWood()">Holz fällen</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the js:

```
var woodProgressColor = document.querySelector("progress, .WoodProgressBar");
        console.log(woodProgressColor);
        if (maxWood - woodCount <= maxWood / 100 * 10 ) {
          woodProgressColor.classList.add("Over10");
        }
        else {
          woodProgressColor.classList.remove("Over10");
        }
        if (maxWood - woodCount <= maxWood / 100 * 50 && maxWood - woodCount > maxWood / 100 * 10) {
          woodProgressColor.classList.add("Over50");
        }
        else{
          woodProgressColor.classList.remove("Over50");
        }
```

Do you have any help ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You've got a **lot** of **disconnected** snippets of code. You should provide a [mcve]. Preferable as a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***should work*** - not really. The comma selector choose multiple elements. Your selector should be:

```
var woodBar = document.querySelector("progress.mywoodprogressbarid");
```

in order to select the progress element with that class name.